# Android CountDownTimer slows the application pages transitions

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have Separated CountDownTimer  in every activity in my app, but the problems happen when I switch between the activities , there is delay some milliseconds and I need the switching between the activities becomes directly without any delay. for instance , I'm in the activity 1 which has CountDownTimer , when I press the button to go to the second activity that has CountDownTimer  also , it takes some milliseconds to bring the activity 2. and this is my code

```
    countDownTimer21 =  new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            strLong = Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            time.setText(strLong);

        }
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent fail = new Intent(Test10_D.this, FailPage10.class);
            fail.putExtra("scorerecord", myscore);
            next.putExtra("scorevalue", strLong);
            startActivity(fail);
            countDownTimer21.cancel();
            //finish();
        }
     }.start();
```

Any suggestions? Thanks Alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You have created two countdown timers in two different activity and when you go from 1st->2nd activity first timer is stooped and 2nd is resumed from value provided by 1st activity's timer.

So Solution is write single common timer in a separate thread like this:
Write your Countdown Timer in a separate service and show the countdown on UI through handler of activity which is on screen.
that's it